# The minimum of two brownian random

Tags: probability

I want to calculate $E[\min(B_t, B_s)]$.

My current method is to split it into

$E[B_s | B_s < B_t]\times P[B_s < B_t] + E[B_t | B_s > B_t] \times P[B_s > B_t]$

Am I right to say that $E[B_s | B_s < B_t]$ is $0$ because $E[B_s | B_s < B_t] = E[B_s | 0 < B_t - B_s]$, and $B_t - B_s$ and $B_s$ are independent?

Comment: All the $B_t$ have the same mean, correct?

Comment: Yes, and assume that $t > s$ for simplicity.

Comment: When random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathsf E(X\mid 0<Y)=\mathsf E(X)$; and in particular $\mathsf E(B_s)=0$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, but we know that the mean of $B_s$ is 0 since it is Gaussian.

Comment: Also by linearity of expectation: $\mathsf E(B_t\mid 0>B_t-B_s) = \mathsf E(B_t-B_s\mid 0>B_t-B_s)-\underbrace{\mathsf E(B_s\mid 0>B_t-B_s)}_{=0}$ so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s<t$, then, remberbering that $\min\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b-|b-a|}{2}$, we have:

$E[\min\{B_s,B_t\}]=E\left[\frac{B_s+B_t-|B_s-B_t|}{2}\right]=-\frac{1}{2}E[|B_s-B_t|]$.

Now, $B_t-B_s\sim N(0,\sqrt{t-s})$. Thus, $|B_t-B_s|$ is a folded normal with mean $\sqrt{t-s}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$

So $E[\min\{B_s,B_t\}]=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t-s}\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}$

Comment: I believe that $B_s-B_t\sim N(0,t-s)$.

Comment: Ups... typing error.